# python sympy integral.doi(). I can't get doit value

Tags: python, sympy, gaussian, symbolic-integration

I want to calculate probality of Gauusian distribution by using integrate. So i coding like this.

```
from sympy import integrate
from sympy import Symbol
from math import e
from math import pi
x=Symbol('x')
mean=30
standard_deviation=2
f=(2*pi*(standard_deviation)**2)**(-1/2)*e**(-((x-mean)**2)/(2* 
(standard_deviation)**2))
print(integrate(f,(x,25,35)).doit())
```

I predict python print a number, because i use doit(). but python show me like this.

```
2.76535477492222e-50*Integral(2.71828182845905**(15*x/2)*2.71828182845905**(-x**2/8), (x, 25, 35))
```

Why python doesn't put number in x?

Comment: If you replace `e` by `exp` from SymPy, will you get what you want?

Comment: saddly, i got error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Samsung/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/asd.py", line 8, in <module>
    f=(2*pi*(standard_deviation)**2)**(-1/2)*exp((-((x-mean)**2)/(2* (standard_deviation)**2)))
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py", line 239, in __float__
    raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")
TypeError: can't convert expression to float